# Magento Fatal error Call to a member function getName() on a non-object while import

Tags: magento-1.6, magento

Getting the following error in my console while trying to import products using CSV
I am using magento core import functionality

```
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in <b>/home/magentosite/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php</b> on line <b>377</b><br />
```

function in product.php file with line no 377 haven't changed core file

```
 /**
 * Initialize categories text-path to ID hash.
 *
 * @return Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product
 */
protected function _initCategories()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addNameToResult();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $structure = explode('/', $category->getPath());
        $pathSize  = count($structure);
        if ($pathSize > 2) {
            $path = array();
            for ($i = 2; $i < $pathSize; $i++) {
                $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();  ---> **This is line no 377**
            }
            $this->_categories[implode('/', $path)] = $category->getId();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

please can any one knows the solution for this? I am on magento 1.6.2

:(

Comment: The value of `$structure[$i]` should point to a valid `entity_id`. My guess would be a non-existing `catalog_category_entity.entity_id` or `catalog_category_flat_store_<n>.entity_id`, respectively.

Comment: post some lines from your csv file that you use for import.

Comment: @JürgenThelen yes you are right I added the tables catalog_category_flat_store_2,3,4 manually because these tables are missing we have facing the reindexing problem after added this tables reindexing is working fine but import showing error what to do now cay you please help me for this table relations ?

Comment: @JürgenThelen able to solve this thanks

Comment: I'm getting same error while exporting the product. what solution you have applied?

Answer (score 0):

The also case if you don't have category in the registry and get its name then this error also occurred like you access direct product link and try to get category on the page through registry this error occurred.
solution to check category present or not.

```
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
        $categoryName = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
    }
    else {
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        if (count($categoryIds)) {
            $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
            $categoryName = $_category->getName();
        }
    }
```