# Magento : Fatal error in basic import

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento default product import functionality under sytem>import/export>import

When i upload the file and click on check data button the the page calls ajax and a error is returned

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php on line 390
```

I didn't have any customization in core  files.

What i have done : 
1) I have replaced the whole ImportExport module with a fresh one
2) I have also found some similar problems and done as their solution was saying there may be indexing issue  so i have truncate all the flat tables and re-index all

Thanks

Comment: Do you have valid categories to products?

Comment: @Renku  yes i have valid categories..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to version 1.7.1, you have this error `_initCategories` function.

```
protected function _initCategories()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addNameToResult();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $structure = explode('/', $category->getPath());
            $pathSize  = count($structure);
            if ($pathSize > 1) {
                $path = array();
                for ($i = 1; $i < $pathSize; $i++) {
                    $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
                }
                $rootCategoryName = array_shift($path);
                if (!isset($this->_categoriesWithRoots[$rootCategoryName])) {
                    $this->_categoriesWithRoots[$rootCategoryName] = array();
                }
                $index = implode('/', $path);
                $this->_categoriesWithRoots[$rootCategoryName][$index] = $category->getId();
                if ($pathSize > 2) {
                    $this->_categories[$index] = $category->getId();
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

You should have a valid entity Id, at `$structure[$i]`. ie in  `catalog_category_entity` table, there should be a valid `entity_id`.

I have seen a similar issue for 1.6.2 version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479623/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getname-on-a-non-object-while-im).

Comment: I am using the category that is already created... that means it has valid entity_id id

Comment: reindex your db and see if a table `catalog_category_flat_store_` came or not. Then try to import.

Comment: Thanks Renku for pointing me i right direction actually the $structure[$i] index contains category id but for some index i was blank i have added a condition their and its fine now but not getting why some index don't have category ids.. :-(

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but for those who arrives here for solution. Here is alternative one :-

in the function protected function _initCategories(), please find the following code :-

```
$path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
```

just comment it & place the following code there :-

```
$category123 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($structure[$i]);
$path[] = $category123->getName();
```

It will work for you.